# Animation alongside dismissal animation of UISheetPresentationController

Tags: swift, animation, uikit

I use the Apple's new `UISheetPresentationController` and want to update the layout of the underlying view controller when the sheet is presented and dismissed.

When the user starts to pull down the sheet, `func presentationControllerWillDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController)` of `UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate` is called and I start my animation like so

```
presentationController.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(
    alongsideTransition: { _ in
        // my animations
    },
    completion: nil
)
```

This works perfectly when the interaction is not too fast. If it is fast, it seems like the animation gets out of sync:

[image]

I also added a handler which logs when the animation is cancelled:

```
transitionCoordinator.notifyWhenInteractionChanges() {
  print("cancelled: \(context.isCancelled)")
}
```

And it looks like the animation is cancelled but the `func presentationControllerWillDismiss` is not called again. When the the gesture is not too fast, the animation is also cancelled but afterwards presentationControllerWillDismiss is called.

Do you think it is a bug that the animation is cancelled but `presentationControllerWillDismiss` is not called again? And does someone maybe know a simple workaround?

**Minimal reproducible Example**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy var openSheetButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Open Sheet", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        button.addTarget(
            self,
            action: #selector(didTapOpenSheetButton(_:)),
            for: .touchDown
        )
        return button
    }()
    
    let orangeView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        return view
    }()
    
    var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        positionElements()
    }
    
    func positionElements() {
        
        // Orange view
        
        view.addSubview(orangeView)
        orangeView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        orangeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        orangeView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        
        bottomConstraint = orangeView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -200)
        bottomConstraint?.isActive = true
        
        // Open Sheet Button
        
        orangeView.addSubview(openSheetButton)
        openSheetButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orangeView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        openSheetButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orangeView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    }
    
    @objc
    func didTapOpenSheetButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // Create modal view controller
        
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        guard let sheet = viewController.sheetPresentationController else { return }
        
        // Configure sheet
        
        sheet.detents = [.medium()]
        sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
        sheet.delegate = self
        
        // Present modal view controller
        
        present(viewController, animated: true)
        
        // Animate something alondside transition (e.g. bottom constraint of orange container)
        
        transitionCoordinator?.animate(
            alongsideTransition: { _ in
                self.bottomConstraint?.constant = -UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            },
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate {
    
    func presentationControllerWillDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        
        print("presentationControllerWillDismiss called")
        
        // Animate something alongside dismissal transition
        
        presentationController.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(
            alongsideTransition: { _ in
                self.bottomConstraint?.constant = -UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.bottomConstraint?.constant = -200
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            },
            completion: nil
        )
        
        // Print when transition was cancelled
        
        presentationController.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.notifyWhenInteractionChanges() { context in
            
            print("notifyWhenInteractionChanges: \(context.isCancelled)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Please provide a [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: Sure :-) I updated my question

Comment: Yeah, you've got some mistakes in your update, but after you fix those, I'm pretty sure you've got yourself a legitimate bug. I saw this appear in the console: `[Assert] UIKit Internal bug: Unbalanced call to _endOcclusion, please file a Radar on UIKit | Presentations with reproduction steps if you hit this !`

Comment: I recommend you try this in the new beta, and if the bug is still there, file it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @matt! I will try it in the new beta and I will give you an update. But I am also curious about the mistakes in my update function. What exactly  is wrong? :-)

Comment: It makes no sense to set the bottom constraint constant and call `layoutIfNeeded` _twice_.

Comment: No you need it, otherwise there wouldn't be a change that can be animated after the animation has been stopped. You could also reset the constraints in the handler of `notifyWhenInteractionChanges` when `context.isCancelled == true`. It is basically the same.

Comment: You seem to think the two animations and layouts are successive. They aren't.

Comment: Delete the two lines you mentioned and you will see what I mean. The orange container won't be animated anymore once it was stopped.

Comment: Not successive. I just want one animation. Therefore I call the layout if needed twice.

Comment: Okay whatever. Anyway thanks for the interesting bug.